# Import data separated by strings to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to import data to python numpy.array from data file like this:

```
VARIABLES = Y Z V W
ZONE
T="1"
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
ZONE
T="2"
12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27
```

My expected result is:

```
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]
  [24 25 26 27]]]
```

I've tried something like

```
data = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=' ', comments=['V','T','Z'])
```

but as a result I received an array of data not divided into separate zones. Thanks for the help!

Update:

It turned out that it is essential that the zones have different sizes. Otherwise there is no problem.

Comment: Make a pass (iterate) over the file and keep the lines you want in a list; then pass the list to numpy. You might be able to test each line with [`line.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) or `line[0].isdigit()` or `all(thing.isdigit() for thing in line.split())`. You might need to strip the end of line character before you test it. You will probably have to convert the numbers to floats in the lines you keep .

Comment: @wwii, I tried to follow your advice and if the sizes of datasets in each zone are the same, then everything is ok. Otherwise, data for each zone is stored in lists inside np.array.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the file; for each line strip whitespace from end; split on whitespace; check for numbers; keep line if it only contains numbers after *turning them into* floats (or mayb ints?); make an array of the result.

```
import io
import numpy as np

f = io.StringIO('''VARIABLES = Y Z V W
ZONE
T="1"
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
ZONE
T="2"
12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27''')

data = []
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split()
    if all(thing.isdigit() for thing in line):
        data.append([float(thing) for thing in line])
print(data)

a = np.array(data)
```